# Append new lines to the existing file in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, file, dataframe

I have a python script that runs a query and stores it in a dataframe as below:

```
 df = pd.read_gbq(queryString, project_id=PROJECT)

 out = df.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('},{', '}\n{')
```

After some processing, I current store it in a json file:

```
with open('/home/user/Downloads/Count1/Count.json', 'w') as f:
 f.write(out)
```

Every time when the program runs, it overwrites the existing file. I was just wondering whether there is a method in Python that appends only the new lines to the existing file rather than overwriting the entire file.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('/home/user/Downloads/Count1/Count.json', 'ab') as f:
     f.write(out)
```